# how to set radio button drawable programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to channge the radio button position. And I found the solution, changing `button = "@null"` and `android:drawableTop="@drawable/"` 
But I want to change this xml code to program code. How Can I add this in program code?

```
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:button="@null"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add a boolean flag to record the button on/off state

```
private boolean isButtonClicked = false;
```

Then you should add a click listener for your button and toggle the boolean flag.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ......
    Button star = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStar);
    star.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked;
            v.setBackgroundResource(isButtonClicked ? R.drawable.btn_star_on : R.drawable.btn_star_off);
        }
    });
}
```